# How to display a dialog box for mobile users only on a non-mobile site

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, dialog

I'm aware of the various ways to detect a mobile browser, but I'm having trouble finding a way to pop up a dialog for mobile users allowing them to confirm they want to view the regular page (and not be switched to the mobile site) even though they are on the non-mobile version of the site. Unfortunately this is the requirement I have rather than a simple redirect.

I had thought I could use jquery mobile, but I'm not finding a way to make the proper rel=dialog stuff work. If there a prebuilt jquery script that does browser detect and pops up a dialog for mobile users asking them to switch to a mobile url or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#my-dialog'), {
            role : 'dialog'
        });
    }
});
```

You can progmatically call a dialog with the `$.mobile.changePage()` function: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

You will most likely want to update the `if` statement that decides if the browser is a mobile browser, the code I posted is just an example that captures Android and iPhone devices.

Here is some documentation for `match()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an
>   Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method
>   returns null.

`null` will resolve to `falsy` and finding any matches will resolve to `truthy`.

### Update

Ok, so to show a modal dialog without jQuery Mobile you can just create a DOM element that overlays the rest of the site:

```
$(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        $('body').append('<div style="position : absolute; z-index : 999; top : 0; left : 0; width : 100%; height : 100%; background : #000; opacity : 0.5; filter : alpha(opacity=50);" /><div style="position : absolute; z-index : 1000; top : 50%; left : 50%; width : 200px; height : 100px; margin-left : -100px; margin-right : -50px;">Your dialog text goes here</div>');
    }
});
```

What I like to do is show a "Notice Bar" at the top of the page that tells the user about the mobile site:

```
$(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
        $('body').prepend('<div id="mobile-notice" style="position : relative; display : none;">copy goes here</div>').find('#mobile-notice').slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am aware of how to do a mobile detect, but am finding it impossible to include any div for the dialog on the actual page. This is a separate site from the mobile site and though I can include the jquery mobile script in the non-mobile site's header, I can't use the jquery mobile css on that page and I think I will have to load the dialog page (with it's own jquery mobile stylesheet) but can't see a way to do this using $.mobile.changePage()...

And is $.mobile available just because I'm including the script? Does it have to be initialized or anything?

Comment: Just create your own dialog using CSS (z-index and absolute positioning, because fixed positioning is not well supported in mobile browsers).

Comment: Without jQuery, the if statement works in the normal `<script>` tag too. Thanks! Worked for me on 11/08/2022.

Answer (score 0):

i have got a solution that might fix your problem.  It uses css and has a MediaQuerie. Pretty much if the browsers width is less than 350px then display the content. Check It - http://jsfiddle.net/Rw6MD/

Comment: I like the idea, but what if I am in landscape orientation (approx. 800px-960px on most new mobile devices)?

Comment: you could always make a MediaQuerie for the height and width of the browser

Comment: `@media all and (max-height: 320px) or (max-width: 320px)`. This doesn't work, are you aware of how to use the `or` statement in a media query?

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox it only works with the `width`, if I re-size the height to be small the `.mobile` element doesn't display.

Comment: sorry forgot to put something in,  Should work now - http://jsfiddle.net/Rw6MD/4/